# We say Reference are const pointers. Why I am able to assign a new variable to ref B? The below program compiles successfully

Tags: c++, reference, variable-assignment

```
#include<iostream.h>

int main()
{
int a=10;
int &b=a;

cout<<"B"<<'\n'<<b;
cout<<"A"<<'\n'<<a;
b=100;
cout<<"B"<<'\n'<<b;
cout<<"A"<<'\n'<<a;
int c=20;
b=c;

cout<<"C"<<'\n'<<c;
cout<<"B"<<'\n'<<b;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

A reference is not a const pointer. A const pointer would need to be dereferenced to access the value. You don't need to dereference references.

A reference is an alias - a new name for the same thing. So the code in your question is valid and a and b refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you are not getting confused with :

b=c;

This will only assign the value of c to b. It will not refer to c. ( It will still refer to a itself)

Answer (score 3):

Your are not assigning a new variable (referee) to `b`, but a new value to the variable `b` refers to, in this case `a`.

Answer (score 2):

A reference is similar to a *const pointer* but not to a *pointer to const object*.

```
const int* p; //can't change the value of *p
int* const p; //can't change p (make it point to a different int)
```

References are similar to the latter - once initialized, they can't be made to refer to another object.

Answer (score 0):

Reference is not pointer at all.

```
int const & b1 = a; // const reference
int       & b2 = a  // non-const reference
```

Comment: Can we say that ref is initialized to one var and then it cant point to other variable.

Comment: Yes, we can. But the value of this `other variable' can be changed.

Comment: I assume it's the value of the 'one var', not 'other variable' that can be changed, you meant.

Answer (score 0):

when you are doing b = c, you are not referring to c instead you are just assigning value of c to b. If you want verify increment value of c and print both b and c.